# systemd in Ubuntu 14.04 backport wants to delete many files upon install - why?

Tags: 14.04, systemd, backport

In Synaptic Package Manager, Ubuntu backport wants to intall systemd (admin, main, version 204-5ubuntu20.20) on Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.13.0-105 generic, and wants to uninstall the following files.  Why?  Will uninstalling these files make my system unusable?

```
account-plugin-jabber
account-plugin-yahoo
cheese
empathy
gir1.2-totem-2.0
gnome-contacts
gnome-control-center
gstreamer1.0-clutter
indicator-bluetooth
indicator-datetime
libcheese-gtk23
libcheese7
libclutter-1.0-0
libclutter-gst-2.0-0
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
libcogl-pango15
libcogl15
libegl1-mesa-lts-xenial
libgbm1-lts-xenial
libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial
libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial
libgles1-mesa-lts-xenial
libgles2-mesa-lts-xenial
libtotem0
libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
libxatracker2-lts-xenial
mcp-account-manager-uoa
nautilus-sendto-empathy
systemd-shim
totem
totem-plugins
unity-contro-center
xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-qxl-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-xenial
xserver-xorg-vmware-lts-xenial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one or more of those packages (probably the X.org stuff) on your system is incompatible with the `systemd` package(s) and the other packages depend on those incompatible packages. Hence why Apt wants to remove them to install `systemd`.

If you tell Apt to uninstall them you won't have a graphical user interface any more until you reinstall the. Your system will still be usable albeit only from a virtual terminal.